# How to access TempData in _layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core

This is the controller. I try to send cart count data to _layout.cshtml by using TempData.

```
//cartController  
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddToCart(int movieId, int quantity)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AddToCart" + movieId + quantity);
            List<CartItems> cartItems = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<List<CartItems>>("Cart") ?? new List<CartItems>();
            Movies movies= new Movies();
            movies = GetMoviesByMovieId(movieId);
            Console.WriteLine("current movie" + movies.Genre.ToString());
            Guid cartItemId = Guid.NewGuid();
 
            cartItems.Add(new CartItems { Id = cartItemId, Movies = movies, Quantity = quantity });

            _logger.LogInformation("Cart items: {cartItems}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cartItems));

            HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("Cart", cartItems);

            int cartCount = cartItems.Count;

            TempData["cartCount"] = cartCount;

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); // Redirect to home or cart page
        }
```

in the layout i access the tempdata like that. I do not see any cartcount in UI navbar. But i can see my console in terminal correctly. Is there any error since i am very new to c# and I have been taken two days already.

```
//_layout.cshtml
}
                    @if (TempData["cartCount"] != null)
                    {

                        var cartItemCount = TempData["cartCount"];
                        Console.WriteLine("cartItemCount in layout" + cartItemCount);
                        <a class="cart-count">test2 @cartItemCount</a>
                    }
```

program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddSession();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSession();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Is that code inside the `body` of _layout.cshtml?

Comment: Yes..insied the body.

Comment: Could you please share your `.net version` used and your `Program.cs` ? I test in my side, whether I test within a get method or a post method, `TempData` worked well. Only when I send a ajax to call the post method, since it returns View but ajax can't handle the view returning, then I can' see the layout to display the content.

Comment: @TinyWang i just added program.cs and my .net version is 7.0.101

Answer (score 0):

Could you please have a test with my codes? If it not worked, could you please create a new .net 7 MVC project and test again? Below are all what I added in my side.

Here's my _Layout.cshtml, like you can see, I put the target content in the main DIV.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="divMain">
        @if (TempData["cartCount"] != null)
        {

            var cartItemCount = TempData["cartCount"];
            <a class="cart-count">test2 @cartItemCount</a>
        }
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in my Home/Index.cshtml, I write a form submit function to mock calling the AddToCart method.

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddToCart" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="text" value="1" name="movieId" />
    <input type="text" value="2" name="quantity" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="test temp data" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's the post method in my HomeController. When it's triggered, it would redirect to Privacy page, which would cause the website reload, so that the TempData would be loaded.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddToCart(int movieId, int quantity)
{
    TempData["cartCount"] = "cart count";
    return RedirectToAction("Privacy", "Home");
}
```

[image]